# Set to set background-image of div via overlay using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a google chrome extension which creates an overlay. When I set the backgroundColor of the div, it div shows up just fine. However, when I try to set the background image of the div, the div does not show up. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendMessage)=>{
  if(request==='execoverlay'){
      let imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      let imageName = "image" + imageIndex.toString() + ".jpg";
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      let bar = document.getElementById('gb');
      bar.style.zIndex = -1;
      div.style.minWidth = "100%";
      div.style.width = "100%";
      div.style.minHeight = "100%";
      div.style.height = "100%";
      div.style.position = "fixed";
      div.style.left = 0;
      div.style.zIndex = 100;
      div.style.top = 0;
      alert('/backdrops/' + imageName)
      div.style.backgroundImage = url('/backdrops/' + imageName);
      div.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
      div.style.backgroundSize = 'contain';
      var label = document.createElement('span');
      label.textContent = "Hello, world";
      div.appendChild(label);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      sendMessage({msg:'recieved'})
  }
})
```

Comment: Declare [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and use chrome.runtime.getURL to generate the URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm I added "web_accessible_resources": [
      "backdrops/*.jpg"
    ] but the console returns the bug: GET https://www.google.com/backdrops/image1.jpg 404

Comment: `\`url("${chrome.runtime.getURL('/backdrops/' + imageName)}")\``

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you so much! It works brilliantly.